# EXCEL [Get Data] from .txt row column is going wrong

Tags: c#, excel, windows, biometrics, excel-2019

Is it possible that the Input Data from our company bio metrics are wrong? because the data that I always getting is not exactly the thing that I am expecting.

Some data are input in the wrong row in excel.
I provided some pictures for you to visualize it also.
thank you so much! :)

[Text File I Got From Biometrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uinjD.jpg)

[Data that given on GET DATA in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LntoI.jpg)

I'm also developing a window application using OPENDIAG AND SAVE DIAG in button.
and the only problem that I am thinking is that there is a problem with the way the data being input in the biometrics, please save me anyone ;w;

Comment: can you show us some code, how do you create your excel file?

Comment: @VDN here is the code I use.

Comment: {
            string Saved_File = "";
            saveFD.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\WhereaboutsFiles";
            saveFD.Title = "Save Text File";
            saveFD.FileName = "";
            saveFD.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls";
            if (saveFD.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)

            {

                Saved_File = saveFD.FileName;
                //The line that does the saving is this one:
                richTextBox1.SaveFile(Saved_File, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);